# Problem with IE css

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Problem with site layout in css.
http://browsershots.org/http://rssreaderbg.net/indexed.htm
Here's the page:
http://rssreaderbg.net/indexed.htm
The problem is in the buttons.
They are truncated and the logo is invisible.
The code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>


    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <style>
        body{
            padding:30px 0 0 0; 
            margin:0;

        }
        #up {

            background:#1ea1de;
            margin-top:-100px;
            height:300px;
            width:100%;

        }
        #logo {
            background:url(logo3.png)no-repeat;
            width:100%;
            height:89px;
            margin-top:-200px;
        }
        .clear{
            clear:both; height:0px; font-size:0px; line-height:0px;
        }
        #nav{
            margin-top:-89px;
            margin-left:300px;
            padding:0;
            list-style-type:none;

        }

        #nav li{

            float:left;
        }

        #nav a{
            padding-left:5px;
            display:block;
            float:left;
            height:104px;
            color:#fdfefe;
            font: 39px Tahoma;
            text-decoration:none;
            background: url(levo.gif) no-repeat;
            margin-top:-72px;


        }

        #nav a strong{
            padding:3px 9px 0 0;
            height:80px;
            float:left;
            display:block;
            cursor:pointer;
            font: 39px Tahoma;
            background: url(111111113.gif) no-repeat right top;
    margin-left:14px;
    margin-top:33px;

        }



    </style>
<div id="up"></div> 
</head><body>
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Nachalo</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Funkcii</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Vxod</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Please don't use link shortening services, you could be linking us to porn for all we know.

Comment: What are they doing, and what are you expecting them to do? Be Specific.

Comment: @Kettler sorry ,I thought that when they are shortened it's not annoying.Sorry again!

Comment: it's no problem, but most people here won't follow shortened links. It's sort of an implied rule, so I don't expect you to have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code is not valid, so it will be rendered in quirks mode. This has a big impact especially in IE.

The namespace in the html tag indicates XHTML, but the code is HTML (as the meta tag is not closed).

You have a `div` tag in the head section, which is not allowed.

So, start by adding [an appropriate doctype tag](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) to specify what flavor of HTML you are using, and make sure that the code is valid.

[HTML validation result](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frssreaderbg.net%2Findexed.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1)

As the HTML is broken, the CSS can't be validated yet:

[CSS validation result](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frssreaderbg.net%2Findexed.htm&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en)

Comment: Thank You!
I moved that div from the head to the body and added this doctype:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Buttons showed ,but the logo is still invisible in IE.

Comment: The document is validated also.

Comment: @lam3r4370: IE doesn't recognise the background style, I think that you need a space between the values: `background:url(logo3.png) no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

First, be ready to always have IE screw up CSS.

Now, why have `<div id="up">`? You would be better served simply creating a background image of 1px wide and repeat-x. Then you could position the logo and menu relative to the page and not to `<div id="up">`.

Looking at your CSS, it seems you are really using a hammer to do the job of a screwdriver.